# Php Parse not working anymore

Tags: php, curl, html-parsing

I tried to parse text from this page my methods were curl and dom but it just returns a blank page. If anyone could show me how to do this it would be greatly appreciated. I am stuck and I don't know here to go from here.

Comment: You might start by posting the code you use, so people can actually try to find out what is wrong with it.

Comment: if you are parsing as XML, it will fail, because there are lot's of xml-errors. Parse as HTML-> http://de3.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Answer (score 2):

The `DOM` code is working as expected. The `<span>` has no Text Node:

```
<span 
    id="ctl00_ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_…_msgTextBody" 
    class="msgBody" 
    style="color:#525B64;"></span>
```

The `DOMNodeList` returned by your XPath will be empty. If you remove the `/text()` test, it will contain the `DOMElement` for the `<span>`, which will return an empty String for `nodeValue`.

The text you are trying to parse is inserted with JavaScript client-side **after** the page has been served to your browser. This does not happen when fetching the page with `DOM`, because `DOM` is not a JavaScript interpreter.

The messages you are looking for are in a `<script>` block. You could parse that block and try to extract them with a Regular Expression, e.g.

```
$xp = new DOMXpath($dom);
$nodes = $xp->query('//script[contains(., "var messages")]');
preg_match_all(
    '~var messages = (.*\]);~',
    $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue,
    $messages);
$messages = json_decode($messages[1][0]);
var_dump($messages);
```

The above would parse and decode the JavaScript into an array of PHP objects, which you can then access with `$message->MessageText`.

See http://codepad.viper-7.com/R985hm

Comment: @Gordon oh well how do i parse this text "Reminding you to - which is a code worth 5SB until 12:25pm PST!" its the main text on the page.

Comment: @Gordon wow! thanks last thing if i may? i looked at the link you provided if i anted to echo string(165) string(29) how do i do that?

Comment: @Dan It's an array of objects, so you can access it like you would access any other array, e.g. `$messages[n]` where `n` is the numeric index of the object you want to fetch. The objects themselves are `StdClass`, so any properties you see there are public. Just access them like you would access any other public property, e.g. like shown in the answer.

Comment: @Gordon ah thats what i thought when i try that i get this error Catchable fatal error</b>:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in

Comment: @Dan because you are not fetching the `MessageText` property but try to echo the `StdClass`. Look at the formatted output. It's clear, isn't it? It's an array with 50 elements. Each element is a stdClass having 7 properties. One of the properties is MessageText. That's the one you want. So it's `$message = $messages[n]; echo $message->MessageText;` or directly `echo $messages[n]->MessageText;`